# Scala how it is happening and why

Tags: scala, types

I have following function for checking whether it is `List[Int]` or `List[String]`. But It is always true if I check as follows. Why and how can I define function to check `List[Int]` or `List[String]` type.

```
if(checkIntCollection(List("q","aa","aa"))){
    Logger.info("it is true")
} else {
    Logger.info("it is false")
}
```

OR

```
if(checkIntCollection(List(1,2,3))){
    Logger.info("it is true")
} else {
    Logger.info("it is false")
}
```

Following is to check:-

```
def checkIntCollection[T](v: T) : Boolean = v match {
    case _: List[Int] =>
      Logger.info("It is List[Int] found")
      true
    case _ =>
      Logger.info("It is unknown")
      false
}

def checkStringCollection[T](v: T) : Boolean = v match {
    case _: List[String] =>
      Logger.info("It is List[String] found")
      true
    case _  =>
      Logger.info("It is unknown")
      false
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in other answer, type erasure makes your match expression check for `List`instead of `List[Int]`, hence the results are not as one might expect.

However, you can use `TypeTag`s to circumvent the type erasure of polymorphic types. Note that `TypeTag`s *probably* use `Reflection` which may impact the performance negatively.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object RichClass {
  def unapply[T](a: RichClass[T]): Option[T] = Option(a.value)
}
implicit class RichClass[T](val value: T)(implicit val classTag: ClassTag[T], val typeTag: TypeTag[T]) {}

def isType[T : ClassTag : TypeTag](richClass: RichClass[_]): Boolean = {
  richClass match {
    case RichClass(elem: T) if richClass.typeTag.tpe =:= typeOf[T] => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like this

```
val stringList = List("A", "B")
val intList = List(1, 2, 3)

assert(isType[List[String]](stringList))
assert(!isType[List[String]](intList))
assert(isType[List[Int]](intList))
assert(!isType[List[Int]](stringList))
```

Answer (score 5):

This is happening because of type erasure. If you compile with warnings you'll notice that it says your type test is useless because the contained type isn't visible at runtime.

At runtime the type of `T` is `List`, not `List[String]` or `List[Int]`

The fact that you're trying to do this at all points to a big code smell - how do you not know what you have?

Comment: U r right I have this warnings. I'm expecting json request by post in given format. So I know I have List[Int] for userId and List[String] for userName. In case any invalid formatted json. I should throw exception. I need some way to find out what type of list I got from post reqeust  [ {
        "userId" : 1,
        "userName" : "user name"
      }, {
        "userId" : 2,
        "userName" : "user name 2"
      } ]

Comment: Try using Play-json, you can define a case class and it will convert the json string into Option[YourType], or you can work with the json tree directly.